# Vue warning and component not showing while using v-form and v-text-field from Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use the v-form and v-text-field components from the Vuetify node package.

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field label="Test" type="foo"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field label="bar" type="text"></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

When I do, and even when that's the only components inside a template, I have [those warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqzj4.png) and the components are not displayed, but still [show up in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/160Bm.png).

Other components like v-container, v-row/v-col or v-btn work fine, and it's occurring on both Firefox and Chrome. I'm currently using vuetify 3.0.0.alpha.2

Thanks for reading through !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in the Vuetify version 3.0.0-alpha.2 `v-form` and `v-text-field` are not in the available components yet (It is just in the alpha process and under development)

[What is included in the alpha?](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#questions)

> Currently most base functionality of Vuetify is included in the alpha. This includes core services such as theme, configuration, and layout. A small subset of base components are also included such as grid system, sheets, and buttons. For full list of available components, visit the UI Component and API sections.

Try using a stable release like [v2.4.7](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/)

Comment: How could I missed that... Anyway thanks for pointing out, I was trying to find a workaround to use Vuetify with Vue 3. I guess I'll have to use good ol' HTML before the actual release of the v3.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to vuetify 3.0.0-beta.1 would solve [the problem](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14733).

Comment: I don't think the question was about the `rules` prop, although it might be fixed as well in the version you mentioned, just a sidenote:)